# Method won't work when list parameter has more than 1 item

Tags: c#

I'm trying to count how many id's in my DB match a List of id's that I give along as a parameter. If there's only 1 item in the list it works fine, but whenever there are more items in the list it returns 0. Does anyone have an idea why this is?

Here's my method (edited `.Where` to `.Count`):

```
    public int? GetAllUserEmailsByRiskIdList(List<int?> riskIdList)
    {
        int? count = 0;

        using (var dbContext = new Entities.DanoneRiskanalysisContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<Entities.Riskanalysis> entities = dbContext.Riskanalysis
            .Count(v => riskIdList.Contains(v.Id) && v.Active == true && v.IsOk == false);
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Here's another method i tried:

```
    public int? GetAllUserEmailsByActionplanIdList(List<int?> actionplanIdList)
    {
        int? count = 0; 

        using (var dbContext = new Entities.DanoneRiskanalysisContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<Entities.Actionplan> entities = dbContext.Actionplan;
            count = entities.Count(v => actionplanIdList.Contains(v.Id) && v.Active == true && v.IsOk == false);

            return count;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use `Count` instead of `Where`.

Comment: When I try to use Count instead of Where I get an exception thrown: "Cannot convert int to Inumerable"? @HimBromBeere

Comment: I can´t see anything in your code where you convert an int to a list.

Comment: Excuse me, now you can. @HimBromBeere

Comment: Eeeehm, not really. Where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: ```.Count(v => riskIdList.Contains(v.Id) && v.Active == true && v.IsOk == false);``` gets underlined and tells me the error. @HimBromBeere